# Reaction ecommerce deployement in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, e-commerce

I linked my GitHub reaction ecommerce to heroku,but it shows an application error while loading the deployed app.Is there any change in configuration or settings in order to make it working in heroku? Thanks.

Comment: Please check your log to see if there is anything that prevents the application from loading.